# Why don't the face bones on this model work?

Tags: rigging, drivers

I downloaded a 3D mesh using the "Blender Kit" plug-in in this specific case a woman. This mesh has the rig all over the body, in fact (in pose mode) if I try to move: arms, legs, hands etc... it works perfectly. The problem occurs when I try to create facial expressions by moving the bones already installed on the face, in fact of all the numerous bones placed on the face only those of the eyes work. Subsequently, exploring the mesh more deeply, I realized that the "Body" object has "Shape Keys" inside with drivers connected to bones, but moving these bones does not seem to change anything in the woman's face. The only "Shape key" of the Body object that works is "expr_happy_smile", which creates a smile on the character's face, all the other "Shape Keys" do not work. Coming to the request for help: I would like to be able to animate my character's face using the bones already installed by whoever created the model. Thanks guys you are saving my life! To better understand what it is, I leave you the link to the project where the "woman" mesh is located inside: https://drive.google.com/file/d/191PBB2wrsNXLUKdiCSvmTaZxicdqbCzu/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because the model doesn't have any weights to any of the face bones.

There are multiple shapekeys that work.  Several work on the face, moving the eyes.  These are actually what you're seeing when move the eye bones-- the face isn't weighted to them, but their position is used to drive several shapekeys.

Several other shapekeys also work, but are corrective shapekeys for knee and elbows and such that you won't notice if you're just looking at the face.

If you want to animate this model beyond what it is currently capable, and this file is what you have, then you will need to rig its face yourself.